# Induction: If $x>0$ and n is a positive integer, then $0<x<(x+1)^n$

Tags: real-analysis

proof so far:

For $0<x<(x+1)^n$

Case $i$: $x>1$. Then $x<x^n<(x+1)^n$ For P(1): $x<x^1<(x+1)^1$ false.

Case $ii$: $x<1$, Then $x<1<(x+1)^n$, For P(1): $x<1<(x+1)^1$ true.

Assume P(k) true, $x<1<(x+1)^k \Rightarrow x^k<x<1<(x+1)^k \Rightarrow$

Comment: Very unclear. Mathematics is better if written in full sentences. Here, I have no idea what you assume to be true and what you are trying to prove. Are you proving the statement by induction?

Comment: good advice, im using Kirkwood analysis text and in the back of book in hints to consider both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a proof by induction, you need to do two steps:

1. Prove that the statement holds for $n=1$. That is, replace all values of $n$ in the statement with $1$ and prove that the statement is true. In your case, you need to prove that $0<x<(x+1)^1$. There is no separation of cases needed.
2. Assume that the statement is true for $n$ and show that it follows that it is true for $n+1$. In your case, you assume that $0<x<(x+1)^n$. Then, prove that $$x<(x+1)^{n+1}$$ which shuold be easy since $x+1>1$, meaning that $(x+1)^n<(x+1)^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

As $y=1+x>1$ and $y>x$, you only have to prove that if $y>1$, then for all $n\ge 1$, $y^n>y$. This is proved with a trivial induction:

If $y^n>y$ for some $n$, then $y^n>1$, whence multiplying both sides by $y$, we get $\;y^{n+1}>y$.